# CMake - Can't link shared library (subdirectory)

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am using CLion and mingw-w64.

My executable's CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(test_exe)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "D:\\test")

add_subdirectory(test_lib)
include_directories(test_lib/include;test_lib/deps/include)
link_directories(test_lib/deps/lib)

add_executable(test_exe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_exe test_lib)
```

test_lib's CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(test_lib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(include;deps/include)
link_directories(deps/lib)

file(GLOB_RECURSE LIB_SOURCES "include/*.*" "src/*.*")

add_library(test_lib SHARED ${LIB_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(test_lib libfreetype.a libpugixml.dll.a)
```

The problem is that when I add library with `add_library(test_lib SHARED ${LIB_SOURCES})` I get `undefined reference` errors but when I add the library with `add_library(test_lib ${LIB_SOURCES})` it works perfectly.

An empty project links as expected (both SHARED and STATIC) but I wonder why this one is not working? Because of the libraries I link in the test_lib's CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 0):

When you build a static library, there is no linking taking place. It doesn't check that you have all required libraries.

When you do the same for shared librarie,s then on some platforms (like Windows, or on Linux with -X defs, I think), you need to solve all references.

And you have a shared library.

Comment: I did not get what should I do. Can you explain a little more or post a link about?